# Only one layout design and fit for all screen sizes in portrait mode for iPhone

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am new in IOS development, Can anyone suggest me how to design only one layout in storyboard and it will fit for all screen sizes(like iPhone4, iPhone5...) in portrait mode. If I am setting constraints for iPhone5 than it is not fitting for iPhone5. Please send me any demo project link.

I am creating layout using size classes(width compact height regular), set all constraints but it is not working for iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPhone6+.
what I have to do to fit in all screen sizes in portrait mode? Which size class I have to select to design the layout for iPhone in portrait mode?

Anyone plz suggest me on this.

Comment: @Akshansh Thakur can you suggest me on this.?

Comment: Being new in iOS development, there is no way to avoid _learning_.

Comment: tell me any solution, How to use single storyboard, and layout fit for all screen sizes ?@gnasher729

Answer (score 0):

You should take the time to do this tutorial. It explains very well the basics of auto layout

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2